# Save postgres database from broken ubuntu 10.04 server

Tags: postgresql, backup, migration

Recently a database server with an important db broke (some grub linux issue that I'd prefer not to solve).

I can still access the filesystem. Is there a chance to transfer the database by only moving some directories with content to an equal machine?

This is a 32 bit ubuntu 10.04 with postgres 8.4

**Edit:** On ubuntu 10,04 the postgresql data directory is `/var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main` and not `/usr/local/pgsql/data`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [backing up the "data directory"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/backup-file.html) is what you want.

Moving the whole directory to a new server should be what you might look into. This will move everything within the cluster. From there, you can drop, move,... your single databases as you need to.

Comment: @mit: Note this will move the whole cluster rather than just the one database - you can do this to an intermediate server and then [dump/restore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/how-to-copy-postgres-database-to-another-server) if you only want one database

Comment: @Jack I added it to the answer. Good info!

Answer (score 5):

You might find this interesting:

[Forensic Analysis of Corrupted Databases](http://www.pgcon.org/2010/schedule/events/234.en.html) (PGCon 2010)

Comment: Interesting. The talk starts about 5min in the audio file.